# splitting values from multiple hidden fields - then grouping all first values, second , third etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

Brains not working today and can't find a nice way of doing this.

So i have multiple hidden fields like this -

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnMews" class="split"  />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnVTE" class="split" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnBleep" class="split" />
```

the values in the hidden fields will be a comma seperated lists.

"2,7,3"

"Yes,Yes,No"

"4279, 4340, 4146"

So the idea is that the first value in each box is one set of answers from a form, the second values are another set etc.

I need to strip out all the first values and display in a div (with a date and time stamp)

My idea was to use jquery and grab each hidden field that i want to work with by class like this

```
$('.split').each(function(){

   var txtSplit = $(this).val().split(",");

   for(var i=0; i<txtSplit.length;i++)
   {
      //Not sure what to do here
   }

});
```

And this is where i'm stuck, i know i'm probably coming at it from the wrong angle but can't seem to get past this stage.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code:

```
$('.split').each(function(){
   var txtSplit = $(this).val().split(",");

   for (var i=0; i < txtSplit.length;i++) {
        if ($('#my_data' + i).length > 0) {
            // If we've already added the paragraph with data to theDiv
            // select the paragraph and append the next value
            $('#my_data' + i).append(" " + txtSplit[i]);
        } else {
            var toAppend = $('<p></p>').attr('id', 'my_data' + i);
            toAppend.text(txtSplit[i]);
            $('#theDiv').append(toAppend);
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using, instead of class='split', name='split'.
This way:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnMews" name="split"  />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnVTE" name="split" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnBleep" name="split" />
```

And the javascript:

```
var inps = document.getElementsByName('split');
var str = '';
for(var i=0; i<inps.length; i++){
if(i != i-1)
        str += inps[i]+',';
else
    str += inps[i];
}
alert(str);
```